# I am using node-fetch to fetch from pagespeedinsights and it is returning an html page that says that Our systems have detected unusual traffic, etc

Tags: node.js, pagespeed-insights, node-fetch

I'm using node-fetch to fetch from pagespeedinsights' api and it returns google's little Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network. page as an HTML document. How can I fix this (it was working earlier and fetching correctly)... I did do some testing on the speed and may have spammed it with a couple hundred calls but that shouldn't break it right? I AM using an API key for it as well.